# How do I play an embed video in full screen only if the button pressed?

Tags: javascript, video-embedding

I want to do something that Google has done on their Project Jacquard website (https://atap.google.com/jacquard/). I want to open an embedded video to be played in full screen (only if a button is pressed) as it is done in the Introducing Project Jacquard part. But I do not wish to use AngularJS.

Comment: They are not playing a video in fullscreen though... they just fill the screen with a black background and center a simple embedded video in the screen.

Comment: `youtubeModal('qObSFfdfe7I', 'Welcome to Project Jacquard')` they call this function, I imagine the function insert into the DOM an element that contain the video player, set the element to use 100% of the window and if the browser allow it enters it into full screen mode...

Comment: I need the video to be played only if I press the play button. Any suggestions on that? I do not want to open the video as soon as page loads